# Run multiple identical fig environment on the same host

Tags: docker, fig

Imagine : 2 developers have an ssh access and can git clone a project with a fig.yml file. they clone the project with the **same directory name** ... therefore they can't launch the project 2 times to work independently on the source code.

The firt `fig up` will create the conatiners. OK. but the second will just recreate the **same** containers (not create another **totally separate running instance** of the project) ... how can I tackle this pb ?

Thanks !

Comment: Can I use th FIG_PROJECT_NAME env var for this purpose ?

Comment: `export FIG_PROJECT_NAME=<project_name>`is one way to set it, `-p <project name>` is another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `-p, --project-name` option to use a name of your choice instead of using the directory name.

```
fig up -p my_unique_name
```

It's still possible to have collisions if two developers choose the same name, you may want to establish naming conventions to avoid this.